# C# copy files from local disk to azure blob storage

Tags: c#, azure, azure-web-app-service, azure-blob-storage, .net-4.8

I am struggling with the following problem that is driving me nuts.
I am trying to copy files from my C# webapp from local disk to an Azure fileshare or blob storage. When I run this from my development environment in debug mode it works perfect, however when I run the app from Azure my program throws an error. As it looks the webapp has no access to the local files. Does anyone know this and if so what can I do? Does anyone have an idea how to implement this?

Many thanks in advance to the group.

Comment: Did you read this? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/operating-system-functionality#types-of-file-access-granted-to-an-app

Comment: show us what you got. any exception or code block?

Comment: Local files for web app are not the local files on your computer.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks @David Browne and Gaurav Mantri for the Comment

The error occurs because your web app running in Azure is not able to access the files on your local machine.

To copy files from local disk to `Azure blob storage`, you can use the `Azure.Storage.Blobs` library, provides classes and methods to work with blob storage.

***Code to copy a file from local disk to Azure blob storage:***

I have uploaded the local files to azure using an MVC application after deploying it to azure.

Controller code to copy the files to azure.

```cs
[HttpPost]
 public async Task<IActionResult> Upload(IFormFile files)
     {
            await _blobStorage.UploadBlobFileAsync(files);
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
     }
```

***Code to upload files***

```cs
    byte[] dataFiles;
                CloudStorageAccount cloudStorageAccount = CloudStorageAccount.Parse(_storageConnectionString);
                CloudBlobClient cloudBlobClient = cloudStorageAccount.CreateCloudBlobClient();
                CloudBlobContainer cloudBlobContainer = cloudBlobClient.GetContainerReference(_storageContainerName);

                BlobContainerPermissions permissions = new BlobContainerPermissions
                {
                    PublicAccess = BlobContainerPublicAccessType.Blob
                };
                string systemFileName = files.FileName;
                await cloudBlobContainer.SetPermissionsAsync(permissions);
                await using (var target = new MemoryStream())
                {
                    files.CopyTo(target);
                    dataFiles = target.ToArray();
                }
                CloudBlockBlob cloudBlockBlob = cloudBlobContainer.GetBlockBlobReference(systemFileName);
                await cloudBlockBlob.UploadFromByteArrayAsync(dataFiles, 0, dataFiles.Length);
```

**View to choose files.**

[image]

```cs
{
  "Logging": {
    "LogLevel": {
      "Default": "Information",
      "Microsoft.AspNetCore": "Warning"
    }
  },
  "AllowedHosts": "*",
  "BlobConnectionString": "DefaultEndpointsProtocol=https;AccountName=storagedemo;AccountKey="AccountKey";EndpointSuffix=core.windows.net",
  "BlobContainerName": "blob-container"
}
```